# json.serialize returning null

Tags: json, list, serialization

```
List<ClassName.CustomerDetails> CustomerDetailsList = new List<ClassName.CustomerDetails> (); 
  ClassName.CustomerDetails custDetails = new ClassName.CustomerDetails(); 
       custDetails.CustomerEffectiveDate = customerResponse.CustomerEffectiveDate;
       custDetails.RegionName = customerResponse.RegionName;
       custDetails.CustomerStatus = customerResponse.CustomerStatus;
       custDetails.AccountManager = customerResponse.AccountManager;
       CustomerDetailsList.add(custDetails);

       String jsonOutputString = json.serialize(CustomerDetailsList);
```

I have a list of object type   CustomerDetails which is defined in ClassName.

List is returned as :

```
CustomerDetails (CustomerDetails:[AccountManager= Abraham Lincoln, CustomerEffectiveDate=2017-04-21, CustomerNumber=null, CustomerStatus= Active, RegionName=USA])
```

Json.serialize is returning null.

Anything missing or wrong?

Comment: What do you mean, "is returning null"? As far as I'm aware, JSON.serialize can't return a null string.

Comment: @sfdcfox  Dev Console ->  USER_DEBUG [173]|DEBUG|jsonOutputString null (If I print the string)

Comment: @SFDCRookie please try this serialize(objectToSerialize, suppressApexObjectNulls) signature

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty json.serialize is working for other lists of similar structure . So I am wondering what could be wrong in this ?

Comment: @SFDCRookie : Your Lists looks perfect and I dont see much of an issue in your logic as well.  Taking Blind guess here.. Check if you have any conflicts in namespaces.

Comment: Naming something "ClassName" sounds like it could possibly cause an internal name clash - can you try renaming your class to something else? (unless you have sanitized the code for us, which of course could be obscuring the actual error)

Comment: @CasparHarmer- Yes it's sanitized .

Comment: All - Thanks for your help . I was instantiating the list two times and hence it was coming null outside the Try block.